# Encounter issue with `find_package` command in Visual Studio CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm operating under a new learning curve here with c++ and using CMake in Visual Studio. Here is the partial code up until the point where I receive the error:

```
project(libfranka
  VERSION 0.8.0
  LANGUAGES CXX
)

list(INSERT CMAKE_MODULE_PATH 0 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

if(MSVC)
  add_compile_options(/W0)
else()
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra)
endif()

set(THIRDPARTY_SOURCES_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty" CACHE PATH
  "Directory for third-party sources")

## Dependencies
find_package(Poco REQUIRED COMPONENTS Net Foundation)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
```

Once it hits the first `find_package` is where I encounter the error:
[image]

Here is the code within `FindPoco.cmake`.

```
find_package(Poco COMPONENTS ${Poco_FIND_COMPONENTS} CONFIG QUIET)
if(Poco_FOUND)
  return()
endif()

find_path(Poco_INCLUDE_DIR Poco/Poco.h)
mark_as_advanced(FORCE Poco_INCLUDE_DIR)

foreach(component ${Poco_FIND_COMPONENTS})
  set(component_var "Poco_${component}_LIBRARY")
  find_library(${component_var} Poco${component})
  mark_as_advanced(FORCE ${component_var})
  if(${component_var})
    set(Poco_${component}_FOUND TRUE)
    list(APPEND Poco_LIBRARIES ${component})
    if(NOT TARGET Poco::${component})
      add_library(Poco::${component} SHARED IMPORTED)
      set_target_properties(Poco::${component} PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${Poco_INCLUDE_DIR}
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${${component_var}}
      )
    endif()
  endif()
endforeach()

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(Poco
  FOUND_VAR Poco_FOUND
  REQUIRED_VARS Poco_INCLUDE_DIR Poco_LIBRARIES
  VERSION_VAR Poco_VERSION
  HANDLE_COMPONENTS
)
```

I installed `poco` using `vcpkg` in a directory titled `vcpkg`. Within the `vcpkg` directory is the `libfranka` directory, which houses the `CMakeLists.txt` file that I compile in Visual Studio. Here is an image of that directory:

[image]

Finally, here is the tutorial that I am using: https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/installation_windows.html#building-from-source

EDIT:

Per the link I followed the instructions for solving the build dependencies and here is an image of that:
[image]

Then I ran the `CMakeLists.txt` again and in the `CMake Settings` this is what I see:

[image]

Note also that I ran through the install of poco again and I noticed this and am unsure if it could be the source of the problem or if it means nothing (again, this was the out put after running `vcpkg install poco`):

[image]

After this I still receive the same error.

Does anyone see what it is that I am doing incorrectly?

Thank you!

Comment: What's in `FindPoco.cmake`? Where have you installed Poco? Should `THIRDPARTY_SOURCES_DIR` exist? It doesn't seem to in your screenshot. Please show a [mre]

Comment: Ok, I added what you requested. To answer you question about `THIRDPARTY_SOURCES_DIR`: I am doing this through a tutorial and so I am a bit hesitant to say that something should not belong. Here is that: https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/installation_windows.html

Comment: Those instructions tell you how to specify the poco path, have you done that?

Comment: Do you mean the instructions in the link that I sent you?

Comment: Oh, in that hint. no, because I thought this wast an alternate way of doing what I just did

Comment: So I tried that hint from the command line in VS and it gave me the same error. Perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: poco is installed in the directory `/path/to/vcpkg` if that is what you meant.

Comment: have you set `cmakeCommandArgs` as specified in the instructions?

Comment: No, because the error was occurring before that when I ran, `Choose File > Open > CMake > C:PathTolibfrankaCMakeLists.txt.` But I see your point and I did try, but I cannot find the `Change CMake settings` directory anywhere when I try, `Open CMake > Change CMake settings > libfranka`. Am I to access the `CMake` directory as I did above, `File > Open > CMake`?

Comment: in vs 2019 the menu is "project", "cmake settings"

Comment: Ok, I did this and my documentation is in the main post above. Note that this was done in the `.json` file as I could not find the directory mentioned in the instructions, but it was effective for `eigen3`, at least.